# Load and run extensions on forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I need to go back to home default view on Forge Viewer,  after a few times go for searching and follow some tutorials to load extension i have something like this

```
let res =  _viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.GoHome')
        if(res){
           _viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.GoHome', (gohome)=>{
               gohome.active()
           })
```

It not work for me and have an error like "gohome is not a function" ?. Did i do something wrong  ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition problem in your code.

I will not get into details here, but briefly speaking, things like ***"gohome is not a function"*** usually means that you use an object before it was fully created/initialized.

Try changing your code into:

```
_viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.GoHome').then(
        (gohome) => {
            gohome.active();
        })
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: I've also try  this but  it not work too .I try to print out "gohome " and have something like this but have the same error before.  **bold  proto__: Extension
activate: ƒ ()
constructor: ƒ GoHomeExtension(viewer, options)
deactivate: ƒ () **